# Converting a text column containing images to BLOB column makes things break

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a database with user profiles and a column for the profile picture. Right now the column type is TEXT, however I want to change it to a BLOB. However changing the column causes the images to not output correctly and become corrupted. How can I solve this problem?

I have tried converting the column to BLOB using Phpmyadmin however this causes the problem. The code stays the same. When I convert the BLOB back to text this fixes the problem, however I want the column to be BLOB for easier maintenance.

Php 7.3.5 Mysql 8.0.16

Code that outputs the image:

```
<?php
/* Error handler. Code not shown. Works fine */

/* Checks the login state. Code not shown. Works fine */

$default_pic = base64_decode('Default pic');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
if ($login_state == false) {
  /* Echo a not logged in picture if the user is not logged in */
  echo $default_pic;
} else {
  /* gets the profile picture from the database */
  $client_un = $_SESSION['client_un'];
  $mysqli = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "userdata");
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT profilepic FROM userdata WHERE username=?");
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $client_un);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($profile_pic);
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();
  if ($profile_pic == '') {
    /* echo a blank picture if the user has not set a picture before */
    echo $default_pic;
  } else {
    /* Echo the profile picture. This part has problems */
    echo $profile_pic;
  }
}
?>
```

I am expecting that both versions with the text and BLOB column type will output the same thing but when the column is a BLOB the output is a corrupted picture.